# How can I know when an MQ queue manager was restarted?

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a set of IBM MQ queue managers and would like to know when one of them was restarted or when it automatically failed over to the standby instance.

The queue managers are seated on AIX

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this information from the `AMQERR01.LOG` of the queue manager or by running `DIS QMSTATUS ALL`.

Comment: Thanks. Checking the `AMQERR01.LOG` now to see if I can pick up something

Comment: Did you try the command I provided,  it will show both start date and start time.

Comment: Yes please. I have marked it as an answer. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Queue Manager START events are emitted (provided they are enabled), and include information about whether it was a multi-instance failover. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.doc/q049990_.htm

Comment: Thanks Mark. Checked the queue `SYSTEM.ADMIN.QMGR.EVENT` as per the documentation but the information I found could not help.